# how to pass the string from one viewcontroller to another?

Tags: ios

I have an Iphone application in which I am passing strings from  one view controller to another. My string is added as a property in the class. But when I am trying to pass the string it crashes with the message of deallocated instance. ( -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance). My code looks like this

```
RewardsViewController *rewards=[[ RewardsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@" RewardsViewController" bundle:nil];    
rewards.rewardsshopinfoname=stringshopname;
rewards.rewardsshopinfoaddress1=address1 ;
rewards.rewardsshopinfoaddress2=address2;
rewards.rewardsshopinfopoints=total;
rewards.rewardsarray=self.shoprewardsArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rewards animated:YES];
```

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: you have a space at the start of your nib name. Probably failing to load the nib. Unrelated, but I recommend using camel case conventions to name your properties/functions (ie rewardsShopInfoName rather than rewardsshopinfoname). It's easier to read.

Comment: how are you declaring your property?

Comment: @Dima  then the error message will be different?

Comment: @Dima is `space explorer` too :p So he figured out that space problem :)

Comment: @Dima sorry.i was done it by making that view controller as my property in the sending view controller.in that case u r right.but in this question the same error is coming even if i remove the space,anyway thanKs

Comment: Can you post code from `RewardsViewController`? Particularly interested in the property initialization code. Are the properties IBOutlets hooked up to your nib?

Comment: no for wat we have to create iboutlets for nsstring?

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You have a space in your nib name, which could be causing your problem.
2. You should strongly consider using ARC for your development. All of your memory management problems are solved and in many cases, improved by ARC.
3. What attributes are you giving your properties? ie (nonatomic, retain)?